# Heroku, unable to access jarfile. Again

Tags: heroku, kotlin, jar

Yes, I know, there are many question about similar problems, but I haven't found an answer for me. 
I want to host a telegram bot written in Kotlin on Heroku.
My gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
    id 'distribution'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'mybot'
    version = '0.1'
}

group 'ru.ilagent.mybot'
version '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'io.github.seik.kotlin-telegram-bot:telegram:0.3.4'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task stage {
    dependsOn installDist
}
```

I follow the instruction https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-kotlin#deploy-the-app , also I've added stage and jar. I can push my bot to heroku and call ps:scale successfully. But nothing works. When I'm finding out logs, I see the error: "Unable to access jarfile build/libs/mybot-0.1.jar" . When I call the jar task locally, jar-file is created with a path mentioned in the log.
Also I've created Procfile

```
web: java -jar build/libs/mybot-0.1.jar
```

Something went wrong (. Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's working code:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
}

version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'io.github.seik.kotlin-telegram-bot:telegram:0.3.4'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

mainClassName = 'ru.ilagent.mybot.MainKt'
task stage {
    dependsOn installDist
}
```

and Procfile

```
web: build/install/mybot/bin/mybot
```

Hope that be helpful for anybody)